# call a Method from One Repository to another Repository Symfony2

Tags: mongodb, symfony-2.1

Hi I am using symfony2 With ODM, I want to call a function from one reposotory to another repository to re-use it. I did not get a way to call it directly.

Following my code.

//My LedgerRepository.php

```
class LedgerRepository extends DocumentRepository
{

public function ProfitLoss(){
//Some re-usable code

  }
 }
```

//My BudgetRepository.php

```
class BudgetRepository extends DocumentRepository
{
 //So here I want to call method ProfitLoss() from LedgerRepository


}
```

how to make it possible please guide.

Thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

In this case good old inheritance may come to the rescue.  Both `Ledger` and `Budget` deal with financial transactions.  Why not this?:

```
class TransactionsRepository extends DocumentRepository
{
    public function ProfitLoss() {}
}

class LedgerRepository extends TransactionsRepository {}
class BudgetRepository extends TransactionsRepository {}
```

In this case both `Ledger` and `Budget` can "share" methods in `TransactionsRepository`.

Comment: I did this with following way:

use Edu\AccountBundle\Document\BudgetRepository as Budget;
And then called:

Budget::getProfitLossAccountsDetails($dm, $session, $dataPostedToIncomeExpense)